# How to create model instance with associations in sequelizejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I want to create persistent model with it association from raw json data

```
var data = {
    id: 77
    name: "Fred"

    parent_id: 887
    parent: {
       id: 887,
       name: "Ted"  

       things: [
          { id:991, name: "some", parent_id: 887 },
          { id:992, name: "another", parent_id: 887 },
          { id:993, name: "cu", parent_id: 887 }
       ]
    }


}
```

I simplify my data (i have a lot of association in model and some associations in  associated submodel )

i try use Model.create(data, options)
with options.include: [SubModel] but it not work. it create only row in db with main model
and ignore SubModel

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to create a model instance based on existing data is by using [build](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-build) function. But creating model instance with the related model instance is also a little bit tricky.

So the solution (based on your JSON data) is more like

```
const thingsData =  [
  { id:991, name: "some", parent_id: 887 },
  { id:992, name: "another", parent_id: 887 },
  { id:993, name: "cu", parent_id: 887 }
]

const things = ThingsModel.build(thingsData) // this will be an array of ThingsModel instance

const parentData = {
  id: 887,
  name: "Ted"
}

const parent = ParentModel.build(parentData)

// manually injecting the things instances
parent.dataValues.things = things

const personData = {
  id: 77,
  name: "Fred",
  parent_id: 887
}

const person = PersonModel.build(data)

person.dataValues.parent = parent
```